# "parsing expression" error when using the Info button for an array element in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I have a NSDictionary (coming from a JSON object)
One of the key/value is an array
I'm trying to get it using the following:

```
NSArray *ingArr = [item objectForKey:@"ingredients"];
```

using watch I can see that "item[ingredients]" is:

```
<__NSCFArray 0xc728cb0>(
{
    amount = "3 tablespoons";
    name = "soy sauce";
    "short_name" = "soy sauce";
},
{
    amount = "1 tablespoon";
    name = honey;
    "short_name" = honey;
},
{
    amount = "1 tablespoon";
    name = "vegetable oil";
    "short_name" = "vegetable oil";
},
{
    amount = "1 teaspoon";
    name = "lime juice";
    "short_name" = "lime juice";
},
{
    amount = "1 teaspoon";
    name = "chopped garlic";
    "short_name" = garlic;
},
{
    amount = 4;
    name = "skinless, boneless chicken breast halves";
    "short_name" = chicken;
}
)
```

My problem is that ingArr doesn't contain the expected result.
What I get when I'm trying to watch ingArr[0] is:

```
(<invalid>) [0] = <error: expected ']'
error: 1 errors 
>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "watch"? What command did you execute?

Comment: The little i sign in XCode when you hover over a variable (I know that in different IDEs it is called variable watch)

Comment: OK. Does `po ingArray[0]` in the debugger console produce the correct result?

Comment: Use this code NSArray *ingArr = [[item objectForKey:@"ingredients"] JSONRepresentation];

Comment: @MartinR - hmm... it produces a good result... weird

Comment: @Boaz: Then it is probably a Xcode bug. I have seen similar problems with the debugger "Variables" view.

Comment: @Boaz : probably the **ingArr** doesn't contain the proper NSArray values.

Comment: @MartinR - I am wondering if this question has value of keeping or deletion. Anyway your answer is correct - if you wish to make it an answer I'll approve it

Comment: @Boaz: I have made it an answer and changed the question title to increase the chance that other people will find this if they experience the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be an Xcode bug (and I have seen similar problems in the "Debugger Variables" view). As an alternative, use

```
po ingArray[0]
```

in the Debugger Console, which works reliably (or, of course, `NSLog()` in your program code).